# incredibuild doesn't use other Agent

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, incredibuild

On **Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12** (admin mode), I use **incredibuild 9.3.5** to build a C++ solution.

I can't use the other agents to speed up my build knowing that I am well connected to the coordinator

the error message is as follows:

```
1>Build started 2/21/2019 4:04:11 PM.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(214,5): error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll". A required privilege is not held by the client
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
2>Build started 2/21/2019 4:04:11 PM.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(214,5): error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll". A required privilege is not held by the client
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

The solution is well built going through the classic VS13 Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Yoni and I am from IncrediBuild customer success team.
I would like to ask you to try the following in order to see if it solves: 
On the Initiator machine, open Agent Settings -> Visual Studio Builds -> Advanced. Under Predictive Execution section, uncheck the Enhance throughput using out-of-order tasks spawning

In case this wont solves the problem, please contact our support (support@incredibuild.com) and I will be happy to investigate this issue.

Comment: The solution was to reinstall **MSBuild** (_Microsoft Build Engine_)
thank you Yoni for your help